# Ionic/Angular pasar valores al constructor desde un método

Tags: javascript, html, android, angular, ionic

Estoy practicando para un futuro desarrollo en Ionic/Angular, al principio probé con Ionic/Vue pero me saltaban demasiados errores. La pregunta es ¿como puedo guardar un valor double(coordenadas) en el form del constructor sin usar input, quiero pasarle el valor directamente desde un método y que el usuario no tenga que ingresarlo.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color = 'primary'>
    <ion-title>
      Camaron
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle color = 'primary'>Coordenadas</ion-card-subtitle>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <form [formGroup]="coordenadas" (ngSubmit) = 'logForm()'>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position = 'stacked'>Novedades</ion-label>
            <ion-input type='text' formControlName = 'novedades' placeholder = 'Descripcion'></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item lines = 'none'>
            <ion-button type = 'submit' (click)='get_location()' expand="full" fill = 'outline' shape = 'round'>Guardar Datos</ion-button>
          </ion-item>
        </form>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Les comparto mi vista y mi lógica

```
export class HomePage {
private coordenadas: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {
  this.coordenadas = this.formBuilder.group({
    novedades: [''],
    lng: new FormControl(),
    lat: new FormControl(),
  });
}
logForm(){
  console.log(this.coordenadas.value)
}
get_location() {
  var geo_options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge        : 30000,
    timeout           : 30000
  };
var wpid = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.geo_success, 
this.geo_error, geo_options);
}
geo_success(position) {
  //this.coordenadas.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  //this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var long = position.coords.longitude;
  var lati = position.coords.latitude;
  //this.coordenadas.setValue({lng: long, lat: lati});
  console.log(long + " - " + lati);
}
geo_error() {
  console.log("Error!!!");
}
}
```

Lo que esta en comentarios es lo que probé y no funciono, el resto del código funciona a la perfección
Los valores de long y lati se muestran por consola sin problema alguno pero al momento de guardarlos los guarda como null, el campo de novedades lo guarda correctamente ya que lo ingresa el usuario, el problema es que no se como guardar lng y lat solo cuando el usuario presione el botón de Guardar Datos, las funciones de geo_location, geo_success y geo_error funcionan juntas para obtener y mostrar las coordenadas. Les agradecería me ayuden a almacenar estas coordenadas en el constructor donde esta novedades, lng, lat y poder pasarlo para posteriormente guardarlo en una base de datos, esto sera mediante una API Laravel que ya tengo hecha y probada que guardara los datos en HeidiSQL
PD: Lo de la base de datos aun no esta aquí, primero quiero pasar lng y lat al constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asignarle un valor inicial usa el primer parámetro de [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor()), el parámetro `formState` se encargará de actualizar cuando creas el formulario.

```
this.coordenadas = this.formBuilder.group({
    novedades: [''],
    lng: new FormControl(100), // <-- este es el valor inicial
    lat: new FormControl(200),
});
```

El resto de los parámetros son los validadores

Para actualizarlo luego sólo tienes que llamar a algo como:

```
this.coordenadas.get('lng').setValue(200);
```

Cuando llamas al método [`get`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) puedes acceder a cualquier control anidado y de ahí cambiar el valor con `setValue`. También puedes actualizar valores si usas [`setValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue) o [`patchValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue) de la clase `FormGroup` directamente de esta forma:

```
this.coordenadas.patchValue({lng: 200});
```

Tu decides que forma te gusta más pero la segunda se usa cuando necesitas actualizar varios valores de una sola vez.

Comment: gracias! Ahora con this.coordenadas.patchValue({lat: position.coords.latitude});puedo asignar los valores al form el problema que tengo ahora es que para hacer uso de las coordenadas debo usar el patchValue dentro de la funcion geo_success(position) y me sale error por coordenadas no esta declarado, alguna idea? no puedo pasar coordenadas como parametro porque geo_location me lo prohibe :( asi no podre guardar las coordenadas donde quiero

Comment: @Andresfc21Recuerda que si usas una función regular en lugar de un arrow funcion el contexto de `this` se pierde y por eso te puede estar pasando de que `coordenadas` no está definido.

Comment: Pude guardar las coordenadas desde geo_success pasando el valor con localStorage.setItem('lng','position.coords.longitude') y luego en logForm() le asigne el valor con this.coordenadas.patchValue({lng: locaStorage.getItem('lng')}). Con lo tuyo el localStorage pude realizar lo que necesitaba, gracias!